# How to set CMake CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS per .cu file

Tags: cuda, cmake

I am trying to set the `--device-debug` flag for a single CUDA source (.cu) file. Setting the flag for the entire project works by using

```
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "--device-debug;-lineinfo")
```

in the master CMakeLists.txt file. But I have a sub-project which is included by

```
add_subdirectory (${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cuda)
```

I've tried to set the property from both the master, and the sub-project CMakeLists.txt file, but it didn't work at all. It won't even recompile the file after adding my commands. This are the commands I tried:

```
set_source_files_properties(test.cu PROPERTIES CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBUGINFO "--device-debug;-lineinfo")
set_source_files_properties(ilm/test.cu PROPERTIES CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBUGINFO "--device-debug;-lineinfo")
set_source_files_properties(cuda/ilm/test.cu PROPERTIES CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBUGINFO "--device-debug;-lineinfo")
set_source_files_properties(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cuda/ilm/test.cu PROPERTIES CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBUGINFO "--device-debug;-lineinfo")
set_source_files_properties(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cuda/ilm/test.cu PROPERTIES CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "--device-debug;-lineinfo;${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}")
```

Is it possible to change the desired compiler flag for a single .cu file with CMake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CUDA_COMPILE( generated_files file0 file1 ... [STATIC | SHARED | MODULE] [OPTIONS ...] )
```

generates a list of object files to be used wih `add_library` or `add_executable` commands. It calls `CUDA_WRAP_SRCS` under the hood and can attach extra commands to be given to `nvcc`. You can compile each source file separately with `CUDA_COMPILE` command and different options. Then, you can link them to whatever you need.

Should you need more details please read `FindCUDA.cmake`